# Visual Studio Custom Tool: File wrapper

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, namespaces, code-generation, configuration-files

What I want is typed access to the contents of a file within a VS.NET solution.
I think a custom tool with corresponding custom tool namespace would be the easiest to do (do correct me if there is a simpler way of accomplishing the same thing!)
This would generate code like so:

```
Namespace CustomToolNamespaceInPropertiesComesHere
  Public Module SomeName
    Public Function GetFile() As IO.Stream
      Return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() _
        .GetManifestResourceStream("RootNamespace.FileName.xml")
    End Function
  End Module
End Namespace
```

Basically it creates typed access to a file (An XML file with Build Action: Embedded Resource) within the "Custom Tool Namespace" as specified in the properties of the file.

I do *not* want to use a ResX as I want each XML file to appear seperately in the solution and have the XMLEditor as default editor (So XSD validation can be added if time permits writing one).

Unfortunately little information can be found about these custom tool namespaces. Every example so far also seems to refer to [`BaseCodeGeneratorWithSite`](http://www.gotdotnet.com/Community/UserSamples/Details.aspx?SampleGuid=4AA14341-24D5-45AB-AB18-B72351D0371C) of which the original URL has gone dead.

I'm also asking this in hopes of someone providing something easier to use/implement rather than the overkill of a new custom tool...

Comment: Just a note: BaseCodeGeneratorWithSite is now defined in  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.10.0.dll, which is part of the Visual Studio SDK.